# Webpack 4 Tree Shaking | Documentation | Example Discrepancy

Tags: webpack, tree-shaking

In the [documentation for Webpack 4](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/), they provide an example where the `square` function in the bundle is marked with a comment that says `unused harmony export square`.  I followed along with the example; however, the bundle.js doesn't include this comment.

To reproduce:

1. [Pull the code from here](https://gitlab.com/trevor.screws/webpack-tutorial/tree/stackoverflow_question)
2. Perform a `yarn install`
3. Execute `yarn run build`

Please find my source code here: https://gitlab.com/trevor.screws/webpack-tutorial/tree/stackoverflow_question

---

Edit:

Using Webpack 4.1.1 in development mode, this is the output in my bundle.js file:

```
/***/ 
"./src/math.js":
/*!*********************!*\
!*** ./src/math.js ***!
\*********************/
/*! exports provided: square, cube */
/***/ (function(module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
eval("__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
\n/* harmony export (binding) */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__,
\"square\", function() { return square; }); \n/* harmony export (binding) */
__webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, \"cube\", function() { return cube;
});\nfunction square(x) {\r\n    return x * x;\r\n}\r\n\r\nfunction cube(x)
{\r\n    return x * x * x;\r\n}\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack:///./src/math.js?");

/***/ })
/******/ });
```

Comment: When building in production mode, the function is not included (i.e., it works as expected).  However, in develop mode, the function is not tagged as /* unused harmony export square */, like the documentation says.

Comment: I can reproduce your findings, by following the instructions in the guide. I think it is a documentation error, where while in development mode the `unused harmony export square` is no longer generated in the bundle.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your function isn't being dropped is you are building with `mode: "development"`, which doesn't include a minifier that supports dead code elimination. The relevant details are in Webpack's [Tree Shaking Guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/#minify-the-output):

> ### Minify the Output
>
> So we've cued up our "dead code" to be dropped by using the `import` and `export` syntax, but we still need to drop it from the bundle. To do that, we'll use the `-p` (production) webpack compilation flag to enable the uglifyjs minification plugin.
>
> > *Note that the `--optimize-minimize` flag can be used to insert the UglifyJsPlugin as well.*
>
> As of webpack 4, this is also easily toggled via the "mode" config option, set to `"production"`.

It seems as though Webpack itself does not perform tree-shaking (from what I can tell), rather it delegates the task to which ever minification plugin you use (generally UglifyJS, but `babel-minify-webpack-plugin` is also a good one)

Comment: Hi @rossipedia, thanks for taking the time to respond. I think part of the issue is, I was expecting the `unused function` comment to appear in the bundle for develop mode.  I can also confirm in production mode it is removing the function, so maybe I was having an issue with looking at an old version of the file yesterday or something. I'm going to update the question to be more specific about the missing comment. It looks like the guides are being updated https://github.com/webpack/webpack.js.org/issues/1861 - so maybe there is just a discrepancy between versions.